# Facebook Workplace Account Management API - Update user

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-workplace

I have a workplace application,
I wish to change emailIds of the user via API,
I found that [Account Management API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/account-management/api#coreschema) 
can be used to modify user details via API calls.
My use-case is to modify user email via the Account Management API, which comes under **urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0** schema extension,
I wish to overwrite the existing email with the one I would specify in the requestBody,
From the documentation, I've come up with the following request -

**Url endpoint -**
https://someCompanyName.facebook.com/scim/v1/Users/ HTTP/1.1

**Method type -**
POST

**Request body-**

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0",
        "urn:scim:schemas:extension:facebook:auth_method:1.0"
    ],
    "userName": "abc",
    "name": {
        "formatted": "Julius Caesar"
    },
    "emails": ["abc@gmail.com"],
    "urn:scim:schemas:extension:facebook:auth_method:1.0": {
        "auth_method": "password"
    }
}
```

Is it correct? What modifications do I need to make to the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to change the emails of a user you have to do a PUT request to the address [https://www.facebook.com/scim/v1/Users/{userId}](https://www.facebook.com/scim/v1/Users/%7BuserId%7D)

and you have to change in your payload the email address:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0",
        "urn:scim:schemas:extension:facebook:auth_method:1.0"
    ],
    "userName": "abc",
    "name": {
        "formatted": "Julius Caesar"
    },
    "emails": [
        {
            "primary": true,
            "type": "work",
            "value": "newemail@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "urn:scim:schemas:extension:facebook:auth_method:1.0": {
        "auth_method": "password"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps